# How to implement event handling in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, event-handling

Is there a canonical way in Python, and better yet in Flask, to implement an embedded event handling system?

With event handling, we mean something similar to Symfony's EventDispatcher, which is a simple, embedded system to decouple event dispatch and handling.

The goal is, in a Flask SQLAlchemy API App, to react to creation (or modification) of data objects with creation of additional, derived data objects to maintain a certain sense of consistency. There should be various handlers, each making sure that a certain type of consistency is maintained. These should be separated. It is possible that a handler triggers creation of data, which in turn prompts another handler to create data. This chain should be executed within the context of each request.

These are the options I came across, plus the reasons I ruled them out:

- [Flask signals](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/signals/) - discourage us to manipulate data
- [Pyee](https://github.com/jfhbrook/pyee) - this seems closest to what we need, but not sure how well it integrated with Flask
- [Celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/) - seems more suited for async long running tasks
- [Whistle](https://pypi.org/project/whistle/) - one of many shots at the topic that don't seem exceptionally well maintained
- RabbitMQ, ironMQ or similar - We would like to handle everything within the Flask app

Comment: "We would like to handle everything within the Flask app" - same codebase can be reused. As for "within the Flask App" - it is probably good to have certain layered structure, where Flask is used at higher level (views), but lower-levels do not use Flask magic at all or in a very limited way, so tasks will not need request context. I am also interested in the answer though.